# PHP error fetching json file

Tags: php, json, web

Can someone help why my JSON file can't show? I beginner for JSON. This is my code, its only show blank document. I am learning this tutorial from this website http://contohprogramandroid.blogspot.com/2013/10/contoh-program-android-aplikasi-wisata.html. thank you so much.

this my image when running the code.
[image]

```
//this is the code webservice.php

<?php
class Database {
private $host = "localhost";
private $user = "root";
private $pass = "";
private $db   = "wisata_jogja";
private $conn;

// constructor
function __construct() {
    try{
        $this->conn = new PDO( "mysql:host=".$this->host.";dbname=".$this->db, $this->user, $this->pass );
    }catch( PDOException $e ) {
        echo "error pdo $e";
    }
}


public function showAllData( $table ) {
    $sql ="SELECT * FROM $table";
    $q = $this->conn->query( $sql ) or die( "Failed !!" );
    while ( $r = $q->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ) {
        $data[] = $r;
    }
    return $data;
}

}

$database = new Database();
$response = array();

if ( isset( $_GET['get'] ) && $_GET['get']=='lokasi' ) {
$response['location'] = array();

foreach ( $database->showAllData( 'lokasi' ) as $value ) {
    $kode = array();
    extract( $value );

    $kode['id'] = $id;
    $kode['nama'] = $nama;
    $kode['alamat'] = $alamat;
    $kode['gambar'] = $gambar;
    $kode['lat'] = $lat;
    $kode['lng'] = $lng;
    array_push( $response['location'], $kode );
}
echo json_encode( $response ); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Right click and choose `Show source`, you'll probably see your output. Chrome doesn't support showing formatted JSON data without plugins.

Comment: in chrome use F12 to open the developer console, in the response body you can check out JSON properly, without the need for plugins.

Comment: You could also run your PHP code in CLI (command line interface) mode, it's the solution I prefer when in doubt... `$ php script.php` ...

Comment: Why are you catching the exception that _may_ be thrown in the constructor? if `new PDO` fails, your class should fail, too! Also `or die` must die, oh, and your code is vulnerable to injection attacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition to output is this:

```
if ( isset( $_GET['get'] ) && $_GET['get']=='lokasi' ) {
```

Thus, the script won't output any `JSON` since condition is not met.

From your screenshot it is clear your are missing the `GET` parameters.

In your browser add the parameter to the url:

```
http://localhost/wisata/webservice.php?get=lokasi
```

It's always good to take alternative action when condition is not true.

You should always `echo` something just so you know what is going on:

```
if ( isset( $_GET['get'] ) && $_GET['get']=='lokasi' ) {
    //..............
    echo json_encode( $response ); 
}else{
    echo "cannot output JSON data: parameter is missing!!;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you pass the GET variable "lokasi" to your script ?

Otherwise, it would not go through the if condition

> if(isset($_GET['get'] ) && $_GET['get']=='lokasi')

You can check this by trying to dump the variable or any foobar data inside the if condition to verify your code goes that far, for instance :

```
if(isset($_GET['get'] ) && $_GET['get']=='lokasi') {
    $response['location'] = array();

    $myTest = array('test');
    var_dump($myTest); // Should display something on screen

    // The rest of your code here
```